# how to change the verification url of pie register plugin of wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, url-rewriting, email-verification

how can I change the verification url of pie register plugin? when any user registers it send a verifiaction url like this " http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?piereg_verification=b902g752h4f079d629982f6386&redirect_to=http://mydomain.com/thank-you-for-registering/ " now how can i replace that wp-login.php with my custom login page and that "pie_verification" part also.I checked other registration plugins also but those doesn't even send an email to users. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out myself. I just did a simple trick. I reset the plugin and deleted it. And downloaded a copy of it in the computer, extracted it. Opened the pie-register.php and piewpnun.php on notepad++ renamed all the "pie_veification" and wp-login" with find button. Then I again installed it and before activating it just replaced those files in pie-register plugin folder with my edited files. Which did my purpose. Thank God.